# How to convert 64FC1 float numbers to "bgr8" uint to publish in ROS?

Tags: python, floating-point, int, ros

I need to publish an image after sobel operator, however ROS message does not support float numbers. So how can I publish edge detection message?

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('detector', Image, queue_size=10)

def image_callback(msg):
    print("Received an image")

    try:
        cv2_img = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, "bgr8")
        #print(msg)
        sobel(cv2_img)
    except CvBridgeError, e:
        print(e)

def sobel (photo):


    gray = cv2.cvtColor(photo, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    im_original = np.array(gray)

    #im_original = np.array(photo.convert('L'))
    imy = np.zeros(im_original.shape)
    imx = np.zeros(im_original.shape)

    # Run the Sobel operator

    filters.sobel(im_original,1,imx,cval=0.0)  # axis 1 is x
    filters.sobel(im_original,0,imy, cval=0.0) # axis 0 is y

    magnitude = np.sqrt(imx**2+imy**2)
    #cv2.imshow('lol', magnitude)
    print(magnitude.shape)
    #imgMsg = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(np.array[magnitude], "bgr8")
    message = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(magnitude, "64FC1")  

    pub.publish(message)

    # Construct the plot


def main():
    rospy.init_node('image_listener')

    image_topic = "/usb_cam/image_raw"

    rospy.Subscriber(image_topic, Image, image_callback)

    rospy.spin()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I put "bgr8", it says encoding specified as bgr8, but image has incompatible type 64FC1.
How can I overcome this problem?

```
Received an image
[[  0.           4.           1.41421356 ...,   0.           3.16227766
    4.24264069]
 [  0.           4.           3.16227766 ...,   0.           1.41421356
    3.16227766]
 [  0.           3.16227766   4.47213595 ...,   0.           0.           0.        ]
 ..., 
 [  3.16227766   4.47213595   2.         ...,  51.86520992  30.46309242
   11.66190379]
 [  3.16227766   4.47213595   2.         ...,  57.00877125  39.2173431
   15.23154621]
 [  1.41421356   4.47213595   2.         ...,  59.22837158  45.54119015
   18.11077028]]
```

Comment: Could you copy and paste an example of your dataframe and the output waits? We need this to be able to help you and understand what you need. Thank you:)

Comment: I uploaded images

Comment: We cannot copy a dataframe from image. We use pd.read_clipboard() to copy your dataframe: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html

Comment: I got you now sorry, wait

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to do it I am new(;

Comment: copy and paste in your question the output of `print(df)` or `print(df.head)`.
later if necessary I can edit your question

Comment: The question updated

Comment: So you want to move to multindex columns?

Comment: I want to move 190121 to column (so ch_name and all staff go inside "190121 ") and it has to have the highest level of index. If see the in the second image cities were same as 190121. so they moved from index position to column

Comment: try : `df=df.unstack()`

Comment: @ansev did not work

Comment: show an example of your expected output.  i don't know what you are looking for

Comment: @ansev Please see the second image. In the image you can see three names of cities. I want same , so instead of city names I will have days 190121 ...... 190925